# Largest integer value of $z=x\times{}y$ given $0<x\leq{}a$, $0<y\leq{}b$, and $z\leq{}c$

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

What would be an efficient algorithm to find largest value of $z=x\times{}y$ given $0<x\leq{}a$, $0<y\leq{}b$, and $z\leq{}c$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all positive integers?

For example, if $a=8$, $b=7$, and $c=31$, then $z=30$ (corresponding to $\{x,y\}=\{5,6\}$).

Comment: Can you share the motivation for this problem?  What constitutes "efficient"?  A baseline algorithm is to loop over all $x$ in the range $[\ell,a]$ where $\ell=\lceil c/(b+1) \rceil$, compute $x \lfloor c/x \rfloor$, and find the maximum of those values.  The running time of that baseline is something like $O(\min(a,b) \text{poly} \log (a+b))$.  Are you looking for an algorithm whose running time is $O(\text{poly} \log (a+b)$)?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $A=\{1,\dots,a\}$ and $B=\{1,\dots,b\}$.  For $i\in A$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $x=i$.  For $j\in B$, let binary decision variable $y_j$ indicate whether $y=j$.  Let decision variable $\ell$ represent $\log z$.  The problem is to maximize $\ell$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
   \sum_{i \in A} x_i &= 1 \tag1\label1\\
   \sum_{j \in B} y_j &= 1 \tag2\label2\\
   \ell &= \sum_{i \in A} (\log i) x_i + \sum_{j \in B} (\log j) y_j \tag3\label3\\
   \ell &\le \log c \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Constraints \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} select exactly one value for $x$ and $y$, respectively.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces $z = x y$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces $z \le c$.

After solving, you can recover the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$ as follows:
\begin{align}
x &= \sum_{i \in A} i x_i \\
y &= \sum_{j \in B} j y_j \\
z &= \exp(\ell) 
\end{align}

Comment: This formula is not valid in general. If $ab \le c$, then of course, the answer is $ab$. But if $ab>c$, then the answer need not be $c$ in general. Not every positive integer $\le ab$ needs to be the product of one $\le a$ and one $\le b$ in general.

Comment: Yes, I misread as $z \le xy$.  Working on an alternative answer now.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Corrected now.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this algorithm to be efficient?  It seems very slow, and inferior to a trivial baseline algorithm where you try all $x$.